# Handling common classes in multiple projects in a single solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I currently have two projects say project A and project B in my solution. Now both projects A and B are using similar classes and a copy of each class is found in each project. I wanted to know if there is a better way to accomplish this task. I want to have a single class somewhere and have both projects access common classes from there. What is the recommneded way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Create a third project C in the same solution.
2. Add your shared classes to C.
3. Reference C in the projects A and B. (to do so : in the *Solution Explorer*, right click on *References* in project A and B, click *Add Reference*, click on tab *Projects*, then select Project C, click *OK*)
4. Don't forget to add the correct `using` namespace to use the class in the project A and B.

Or just let your shared classes in project A, or B and add reference to this project in the other project (It depends on the content but doing this way will create a kind of assymetry between the projects A and B).

Comment: Well said -- If you think you could reuse that class in other projects in the future it is well worth extracting it to class C.